# How to get a substring from a string if one string is found

Tags: python

This is a string: `\texample\tDart_181120172410.jpg\tImgCaption\t`

Is there anyway to get the `Dart_181120172410.jpg` and could say to get this substring if only it contains `.jpg` at the end. The actual string is even longer

Comment: it it tab-delimited (\t), Split by tabs, check each for ending with .jpg, done - see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
s = "a.jpg\tnot.llm\tp.jpg\tc.jpg\te.gif\tnix.txt"

all_jpegs = [x for x in s.split('\t') if '.jpg' in x]

print(all_jpegs)
```

Output:  `['a.jpg', 'p.jpg', 'c.jpg']`

[guillaume-dedrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156486/guillaume-dedrie) made a good point in the comment - this will lead to false positives for 
`s=some.file\tthisisno.jgp.gif\tsomemore.files`. Changing it to

```
s = "a.jpg\tnot.llm\tp.jpg\tc.jpg\te.gif\tnix.txt\tnot.jpg.gif\tthis.JPG"
better_jpegs = [x for x in s.split('\t') if x.lower().endswith('.jpg')]

print(better_jpegs)
```

would eleminate that and also handle `'.JpG' or '.JPG'`

Comment: Thank you I was looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()`

```
>>> image_name = s.split('\t')[2]
>>> if '.jpg' in image_name:
        print(image_name)
Dart_181120172410.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in python for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple regex

```
\w+.(?:jpg)
```